# IIS Application Initialization Module for IIS Express and Visual Studio

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

Is there a way to get the [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) that is written for IIS 7.5 to work with IIS Express in Visual Studio?  I'm trying to find a way to test my implementation of System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient which is the entry point for this module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [applicationInitialization causing 500.21 error in IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007530/applicationinitialization-causing-500-21-error-in-iis-express)

Answer (score -1):

A late answer but I was looking for the same answer and you can find it under `Control Panel` -> `Programs and Features` -> `Turn Windows features on or off`:

[image]

Comment: That screenshot appears to configure "World Wide Web Services" which is *IIS*, but my question asks about Application Initialization for *IIS Express* which is usually installed as part of MS Visual Studio.

Comment: The answer is unrelated with the question. IIS Express is not IIS.