# applicationInitialization causing 500.21 error in IIS Express

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, iis-express, http-status-code-500

Can I not have this element in my web.config and run it in IIS Express?

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error The specified handler
>   mapping is incorrect.

```
<system.webServer>
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false" remapManagedRequestsTo="WarmUp.html">
  <add initializationPage="/"/>
</applicationInitialization>
```

Answer (score 2):

For IIS Express you can add the following attributes to the `applicationhost.config` file (location differs dependent on VS version)

Add attribute `startMode` to the application pool

```
<add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
```

Add attribute `preloadEnabled` to application

```
<site name="WebApplication3" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" preloadEnabled="true" >
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="WebApplication3" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59141:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44367:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

In the web.config add the  section

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm" skipManagedModules="true" doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
      <add initializationPage="/" />
    </applicationInitialization>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could remove it from your web.config file.
In my opinion, the applicationInitialization tag is used to warm up your application to achieve  starting up application more quickly.

Details, you could refer to below article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/